# Dynamically setting attributes on an AngularJS Directive element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a directive in AngularJS that has a template which could contain other AngularJS directives. All of my directives require an "id" attribute, so I need to set the "id" on the directive inside the template. However, no matter how I do this, AngularJS keeps throwing this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{field.id}}] starting at [{field.id}}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bfield.id%7D%7D&p4=%7Bfield.id%7D%7D
    at angular.js:68
    at Object.AST.throwError (angular.js:13010)
    at Object.AST.object (angular.js:12997)
    at Object.AST.primary (angular.js:12905)
    at Object.AST.unary (angular.js:12893)
    at Object.AST.multiplicative (angular.js:12880)
    at Object.AST.additive (angular.js:12871)
    at Object.AST.relational (angular.js:12862)
    at Object.AST.equality (angular.js:12853)
    at Object.AST.logicalAND (angular.js:12845)
```

I know that AngularJS is fine doing something like this: `<div id="{{field.id}}">[...]</div>`. It ends up being rendered correctly, with "{{field.id}}" replaced with the actual value of field.id. However once I try to apply my directive to that div, or use the directive as an element itself, AngularJS balks. I've tried all of the following and all result either in the error above or with the directive's ID set to "field.id" rather than the value of "field.id":

```
<!-- result in error shown above -->
<mydirective id="{{field.id}}"></mydirective>
<div mydirective id="{{field.id}}"></div>
<div class="mydirective" id="{{field.id}}"></div>
<mydirective ng-attr-id="{{field.id}}"></mydirective>
<div mydirective ng-attr-id="{{field.id}}"></div>
<div class="mydirective" ng-attr-id="{{field.id}}"></div>

<!-- result in id set to "field.id" -->
<mydirective id="field.id"></mydirective>
<div mydirective id="field.id"></div>
<div class="mydirective" id="field.id"></div>
<mydirective ng-attr-id="field.id"></mydirective>
<div mydirective ng-attr-id="field.id"></div>
<div class="mydirective" ng-attr-id="field.id"></div>
```

In case it helps, the general layout of the directive with the template looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-show="field.visible">
    <!-- some other stuff -->
    <mydirective ng-if="field.type == 'foobar'" id="{{field.id}}"></mydirective>
    <!-- some other stuff -->
</div>
```

I'm seeing an identical issue with another attribute on the directive as well, so it's not limited to just the 'id' attribute.

Shortened version of the directive throwing the error:

```
var application = angular.module('application', []);
application = application.directive('mydirective', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope:{
            mydirectiveId: '=id',
            id : '@',
            // a few other attributes
        },
        templateUrl: 'mydirective.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $element){
            if($scope.id === undefined){
                console.error("The 'id' on mydirective is missing!");
            }

            // more logic... sorry can't post this
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: When you use `id="field.id"` you also have to use `id : '='`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out. I'm not exactly sure why, but AngularJS was having a problem with the isolated scope on "mydirective". When I removed the `mydirectiveId: '=id'` attribute from the scope declaration, it started working again as expected.

Working HTML Template for parent directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-show="field.visible">
    <!-- some other stuff -->
    <mydirective ng-if="field.type == 'foobar'" id="{{field.id}}"></mydirective>
    <!-- some other stuff -->
</div>
```

Working directive code for "mydirective":

```
application = application.directive('mydirective', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope:{
            // mydirectiveId: '=id',       << removed this line, it was the problem
            id : '@',
            // a few other attributes
        },
        templateUrl: 'mydirective.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $element){
            if($scope.id === undefined){
                console.error("The 'id' on mydirective is missing!");
            }

            // more logic
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your directives code,if the name of your directive is myDirective,it should be my-Directive in the html.Also make sure you are using the restrict option on the correct element,attribute

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to share very much of anything; the code I'm working with is proprietary. The directive's name is "mydirective" in all lower-case; it is attempting to display the directive even when it throws the error, it just does so incorrectly due to the error. The "restrict" option on "mydirective" is usually set to "E" but I've changed it to "AEC" in an attempt to get this to work.